# Not sure why this value arises when I am trying to find the tangential intersection?

Tags: discriminant

if we consider the circle, whose equation is given by $$x^2+(y-2)^2=1$$
and the parabola $$y=kx^2$$

We wish to find the values of $k$ for which the parabola will **touch** the circle (not intersect but touch).

**Current Solution**

Let us simply substitute for $x^2=\frac{y}{k}$ into the circle, this gives: 
$$\frac{y}{k}+y^2-4y+4=1 \Rightarrow ky^2+(1-4k)y+3k=0 $$

Now evaluating $$\Delta=0$$
we are solving for the values of $k$ for which the parabola only intersects the circle once.

And so we arrive at $$\Delta=(1-4k)^2-12k=1-8k+16k^2-12k^2=4(k^2-2k)+1$$
$$\Delta=4(k-1)^2-3=0\Rightarrow k=\frac{2\pm\sqrt{3}}{2}$$

However, upon further inspection, the specific value $$k=\frac{2-\sqrt{3}}{2}$$
causes the parabola to never intersect the circle, and thus we only take the other value that we found.

**My Problem**

While this question is "solved", I do not know why such a value of $k$ rose in the first place? Am I interpreting the discriminant incorrectly?

Because such a value for $k$ will make the parabola touch the circle **twice** due to of course, the symmetry of this particular example.

Comment: Since you substitue that $x^2=y/k$, we need a solution to satisfy $y/k\ge 0$. When $k=(2-\sqrt 3)/2$ this is not true. The superfluous $k$ arises from ignoring the restriction $y/k\ge 0$ in the substitution.

Comment: But isn't $k=(2-\sqrt{3})/2$ still positive and still satisfies the inequality described?

Comment: $k$ is positve, what about $y$? We need $y/k\ge0$, not $k\ge 0$.

Comment: And in fact, for $k=(2-\sqrt 3)/2$ the parabola does "touch" the circle, in some special sense: they "touch" at two points where $x$ is a pure imaginary number.

Comment: I still don't understand how this value of $k$ doesn't satisfy $y/k\geq0$

Comment: Why does it satify $y/k\ge0$? What's the value of $y$ if $k=(2-\sqrt 3)/2$?

Comment: Well $y=kx^2$ so the value of $y$ when $k=(2-\sqrt{3})/2$ is $\frac{2-\sqrt{3} }{2x^2} ? $ which is positive?

Answer (score 1):

The step which conceals the introduction of additional, ineligible roots is this one:

> Now evaluating $$\Delta=0$$
>   we are solving for the values of $k$ for which the parabola only intersects the circle once.

The problem here is that $\Delta = 0$ guarantees a root of multiplicity (at least) $2$ to the system of equations, but it does *not* guarantee that the double root is real. Indeed, the second value of $k$ does in fact correspond to a double root, only that the respective root is complex, outside the real plane, so it doesn't count as an intersection of the real conics.

To follow what happens step by step, take the value $k=\frac{2-\sqrt{3}}{2}$ and replace it back into the equation $ky^2+(1-4k)y+3k=0$. Since it's already established that $\Delta=0$ the double root $y$ is given by:

$$
y = \frac{1-4k}{2k}=\frac{3 - 2 \sqrt{3}}{2 - \sqrt{3}}=(3 - 2 \sqrt{3})(2 + \sqrt{3}) = -\sqrt{3}
$$

Then $y= k x^2$ reduces to $x^2 = \frac{y}{k} = \frac{-2\sqrt{3}}{2-\sqrt{3}} = -2\sqrt{3}(2+\sqrt{3}) = -2(3 + 2 \sqrt{3}) \lt 0$ which has no real roots. The complex roots $x=\pm i\,\sqrt{2(3 + 2 \sqrt{3})}$ *do* in fact correspond to the double roots of the two equations, but they are not "*intersections*" in the real plane.

Answer (score 1):

To find the "lost" solution for $k=(2-\sqrt{3})/2$, plot your curves on a coordinate plane where $x$ is pure imaginary instead of real, while $y$ is still real.  What appears as a circle in the all-real plane is now a hyperbola, and the parabola bends down rather than up to become tangent to this hyperbola.

So, the "lost" solution involves imaginary coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in your substitution, we must require $x^2=\frac{y}{k}\ge0$ and thus:

$${y\over k}=\frac{4k-1\pm\sqrt{4(k^2-2k)+1}}{2k^2}\ge0$$

When $k=\frac{2-\sqrt3}{2}$, $\Delta=0$ so we have one solution but: $$x^2={y\over k}=\frac{4-2\sqrt3-1}{2({2-\sqrt3\over2})^2}<0$$

it is negative hence this solution must be rejected. $\Delta=0$ doesn't ensure $y\ge0$.